# An example of a power series that has a radius of convergence of 3

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The problem states "Give an example of a power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}$a$_{n}$z$^{n}$ that has a radius of convergence of 3 and that represents an analytic function having no zeroes. I'm sorry if this is a little simplistic but I really can't think of anything and am having a hard time with this.

Comment: Take your favorite power series with radius of convergence 1 that represents an analytic function with no zeroes, and then replace $x$ with $\frac{x}{3}$.

Comment: @QTHalfTau that simple huh? Thanks!

Comment: Yep! It's not too hard to show that this always works using the ratio test.

Comment: @QTHalfTau that's what I was thinking which in the end yields R= 1/L

Answer (score 1):

Take *any* series you are familiar with and has a finite radius of convergence $r$. Then rescale the argument to be $\dfrac{3z}r$. This multiplies all terms by $\dfrac{3^n}{r^3}$ and yields the desired radius.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the center of the desired power series at origin, the domain of convergence must be $|z|<3$. Indeed, you need a power series of the form $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$a_n.z^n$ which converges uniformly if $|z/3|<1$. One such choice is $f(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}.z^n$.